# how to change ubuntu 15.04 lightdm greeter wallpaper size?

Tags: 15.04, lightdm, desktop-background, resize

i was wondering if i can change the **size** of the background i have selected in **lightdm.conf**

after installing **lightdm-gtk-greeter**

```
 sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

then editing the configuration file , ive changed the directory of the wallpaper i wanted with:

```
 sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
```

the wallpaper changed but the size was very huge.

could not find anything on the internet about it..
is there any solution for it ?

best regards

Comment: ...and the downvote is because...?

Comment: i dont know why

Comment: can anyone help please ?